# How to MEF a initialize method

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I'm new to MEF. I'm wondering when to initialize instances through composition rather than calling their constructor. For example I'm not sure how to approach the following problem in MEF. If Manager class is in a another DLL and referenced in Program

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

        var manager= container.GetExportedValue<Manager>();
        container.ComposeParts(manager);
    var letter =   manager.Letter;
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

//Manager Class is Business Access Layer referenced to Program as DLL

[Export]
public class Manager
{
    private Letter _letter;

[Import]
    public Letter Letter
    {
        get { return _letter ?? (_letter = InitializeComposeLetter()); }
    }

    private Letter InitializeComposeLetter()
    {
        var attachments = new List<string>();

        var details             = new StringBuilder();
        var attachmentDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["attachmentsDirectory"];
        var letterPath          = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["letterPath"];

        if (Directory.Exists(attachmentDirectory))
        {
            var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(attachmentDirectory);
            attachments = files.ToList();
        }

        if (File.Exists(letterPath))
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(letterPath);
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                details.Append(line);
                details.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }

        //*********************QUESTION IS HERE *************//
        var letter = new Letter() //SHOULD I MEF THIS OUT ??? IF SO HOW??
            {
                Subject = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["defaultEmailTitle"],
                Details = details.ToString(),
                Attachments =  attachments,
            };

        return letter;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using auto-implemented properties, you should import the field instead of the property:

```
[Import]
private Letter _letter;
```

Note that if there is not part of type Letter, the composition of Manager will fail. If you want to handle it yourself (as is shown from your code sample) you can use the [ImportAttribute.AllowDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.importattribute.allowdefault%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
[Import(AllowDefault = true)]
private Letter _letter;
```

Finally you do not need the call to `ComposeParts`. This is needed for objects that you have created. If the object is created by the container the composition is done behind the scenes.

So for objects that you create:

```
var manager = new Manager();
container.ComposeParts(manager);
```

otherwise:

```
var manager= container.GetExportedValue<Manager>();
```

**Note** that `GetExportedValue` will throw if the composition fails. There are other `GetExportXXX` methods that will not throw. Choose one depending on your needs.